# Google Play Alpha testing for tablets

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

Hello and sorry for this question but it is my first app uploaded on Google Play :)

I have uploaded an apk in alpha testing, added a group of testers, and the app can be downloaded on phones, but not on tablets. Any tips will be great.

Many thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="zz.zz.zz"
    android:versionCode="25"
    android:versionName="1.0.26" >



 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="zz.zz.zz.TraLaLaApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/splash_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.NavigationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.SeeYouSoonActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.social.FacebookActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.facebookShare.ShareMainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.settings.fragments.RecordVoiceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.settings.fragments.EyeDistanceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.settings.fragments.EyeDistance"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />

        <service
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.utils.PhotoTakingService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service
            android:name="zz.zz.zz.utils.FaceDetectService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please show your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: You are telling Google Play that your app requires a camera, auto-focus and a flash-light via the uses-feature Tag. That are features which some tablets are lacking. Can you double check that the tablets have this features?